# How to point a website to localhost or hostname

Tags: asp.net, .net, rest, visual-studio-2012

How can I make the website point to a local host instance of a webservice if running through visual studio but point to the server using the hostname when running on iis.

I have a ASP .Net web apis project with rest apis that runs on a specific host. I have a separate website project that makes ajax calls to the web apis project. I want the website to point to the localhost instance of the webserver when running through visual studio for it's ajax calls but use the loadbalanacer hostname when deployed and running on the iis server.

Answer (score 0):

You could update your Hosts file to point to the local server?  You should find it here: Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

And here's a good guide: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

Comment: why the -1 ?  I was thinking that this would be a good way to do it without changing the actual project's code.

Comment: +1. This is the practical way. I configure my dev system this. I map 127.0.0.1 to xyz.com and add service reference or host web APIs on this simulated xyz.com. This way I save myself few configuration changes when I deploy the application to real xyz.com. In real time this xyz.com can be a load balancer behind which 100s of servers could be there.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (String.Equals(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToString(), "localhost"))
```

Comment: -1. Hardcoding environment related things is not the right approach.